# Browsers scaling images slows performance?

Tags: image

I have a lot of Photoshop images with a width of 650px. However on my website the images will have a width of 640px (to fit into the layout). The browser will have to scale the images. Will this scaling noticeably effect download speed? Each page will have around six images on it.

Or should I scale the images in Photoshop so that they are 640px wide and the browser doesn't have to do any scaling at all?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's always the best scenario to make things as simple as possible. So put the images on your server as they must be displayed so that (1) you reduce network traffic and (2) the browser doesn't have to do any scaling.